# Responsive design of webmap

Tags: web-mapping, qgis2web

I created a web map with the qgis2web plugin. The map simply contains 2 polygon and 1 point layer. Since I just wanted a static map with these 3 layer I don´t use any basemap.

The final map should be placed in a frame on website and thats where things started to get dicey. The map doesn´t scale correct when the window size of the browser is changed or on mobile devices.

I assume since the map is in a “sub”-frame of the website the

```
width=device-width
```

from meta doesn´t kick in since the frame always stays in the same proportion to the Website.

I´ve looked around for a solution and found this:

[EventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910594/leaflet-responsive-design-creating-different-zoom-levels-for-different-screen)

I would work fine, but I would prefer a more dynamical solution rather than defining the possible widths for all zoom levels..

Note that the map will always be on a fixed zoom level (all zoom controls are disabled). The zoom level should be the maxmium possible with in the frame, so that all Layer-content is visible.

Answer (score 1):

This should work so long as:

- you used the "full-screen" template in qgis2web, which sets the `map` div to `width: 100%`
- your iframe is configured to resize responsively